# Getting error - running Calabash iOS

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cucumber, calabash

I tried to execute a script using Calabash|Cucumber|Ruby for iOS.

don't know what could be the issue, as i tried running other app script it works fine.

I am getting below errors :-

```
no such file to load -- calabash-cucumber/cucumber (LoadError)
/Users/digitaluser/Desktop/features/support/env.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/digitaluser/Desktop/features/support/env.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load_code_file'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:183:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/digitaluser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Don't know what could be the issues.

Comment: How long is your script? Are you able to provide any of it here? If nothing else, are you `require`ing any libraries at the top of it?

Comment: Hi James, My script is hardly of 2-4 lines, and I am not sure if I am requiring any additional libraries. I have executed all the default installation steps.  In fact My other iOS app project works fine.